# The provided URI "https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" is invalid

Tags: node.js, azure

I have some problems writing some files (from debian with the azure cli client) to my storage account. The following error is which i am receiving:

```
root@w01:/scripts# azure storage blob upload -a "mystorageaccountname" -k "Hewaebaweb0F2+E6qbSQbeabewabpr/3ZhKbdawbwabsRINSyQerIA==" "w01-20140213.tar.gz" "backup" "w01-20140213.tar.gz"
info:    Executing command storage blob upload
error:   The provided URI "https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" is invalid.
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   storage blob upload command failed
```

I just updated my node packages on the machine to the latest version (npm update -g). This brings me to the following packages:
ro

```
root@w01:/scripts# npm -g list
/usr/local/lib
├─┬ azure@0.8.1
│ ├─┬ azure-common@0.9.1-pre.2
│ │ ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
│ │ ├── duplexer@0.1.1
│ │ ├── envconf@0.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.27.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ │ ├── through@2.3.4
│ │ ├── tunnel@0.0.3
│ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│ │ ├── validator@3.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ xml2js@0.2.7
│ │ │ └── sax@0.5.2
│ │ └── xmlbuilder@0.4.3
│ ├── azure-mgmt@0.9.1-pre.2
│ ├── azure-mgmt-compute@0.9.1-pre.2
│ ├─┬ azure-mgmt-sb@0.9.1-pre.2
│ │ └── underscore@1.6.0
│ ├─┬ azure-mgmt-sql@0.9.1-pre.2
│ │ └── underscore@1.6.0
│ ├── azure-mgmt-storage@0.9.1-pre.2
│ ├── azure-mgmt-vnet@0.9.1-pre.2
│ ├─┬ azure-mgmt-website@0.9.1-pre.2
│ │ └── underscore@1.6.0
│ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ ├── mpns@2.0.1
│ ├── node-uuid@1.2.0
│ ├─┬ request@2.27.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│ └── wns@0.5.3
├─┬ azure-cli@0.7.4
│ ├── async@0.2.7
│ ├─┬ azure@0.7.17
│ │ ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
│ │ ├── duplexer@0.1.1
│ │ ├── envconf@0.0.4
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── mpns@2.1.0
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.27.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ │ ├── through@2.3.4
│ │ ├── tunnel@0.0.3
│ │ ├── underscore@1.6.0
│ │ ├── validator@3.2.1
│ │ ├── wns@0.5.3
│ │ ├─┬ xml2js@0.4.1
│ │ │ └── sax@0.5.8
│ │ └── xmlbuilder@2.1.0
│ ├── colors@0.6.2
│ ├─┬ commander@1.0.4
│ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ cucumber@0.3.1
│ │ ├─┬ browserify@1.15.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ buffer-browserify@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ └── base64-js@0.0.2
│ │ │ ├── commondir@0.0.1
│ │ │ ├── crypto-browserify@0.4.0
│ │ │ ├── deputy@0.0.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ detective@0.2.1
│ │ │ │ └── esprima@0.9.9
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-browserify@0.1.13
│ │ │ │ ├── Base64@0.1.4
│ │ │ │ └─┬ concat-stream@1.0.1
│ │ │ │   └─┬ bops@0.0.6
│ │ │ │     ├── base64-js@0.0.2
│ │ │ │     └── to-utf8@0.0.1
│ │ │ ├── nub@0.0.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ │ ├── resolve@0.2.8
│ │ │ ├─┬ syntax-error@0.0.1
│ │ │ │ └── esprima@0.9.9
│ │ │ └── vm-browserify@0.0.1
│ │ ├── coffee-script@1.4.0
│ │ ├─┬ connect@2.3.2
│ │ │ ├── cookie@0.0.3
│ │ │ ├── crc@0.2.0
│ │ │ ├── debug@0.7.3
│ │ │ ├── formidable@1.0.9
│ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ │ │ └── qs@0.4.2
│ │ ├── cucumber-html@0.2.2
│ │ ├── gherkin@2.11.5
│ │ ├─┬ jasmine-node@1.4.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ gaze@0.3.4
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ fileset@0.1.5
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ glob@3.2.6
│ │ │ │ │   └── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.12
│ │ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.3.1
│ │ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── jasmine-reporters@0.2.1
│ │ │ └── requirejs@2.1.9
│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ │ ├─┬ nopt@1.0.10
│ │ │ └── abbrev@1.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ rimraf@2.0.2
│ │ │ └── graceful-fs@1.1.14
│ │ ├── underscore@1.3.3
│ │ └── walkdir@0.0.4
│ ├── easy-table@0.0.1
│ ├── eyes@0.1.8
│ ├── github@0.1.6
│ ├─┬ jshint@2.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ cli@0.4.5
│ │ │ └─┬ glob@3.2.6
│ │ │   └── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├── console-browserify@0.1.6
│ │ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.12
│ │ │ ├── lru-cache@2.3.1
│ │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ └── shelljs@0.1.4
│ ├─┬ kuduscript@0.1.5
│ │ ├─┬ commander@1.1.1
│ │ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ │ └── streamline@0.4.11
│ ├─┬ mocha@1.14.0
│ │ ├── commander@2.0.0
│ │ ├── debug@0.7.3
│ │ ├── diff@1.0.7
│ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.3
│ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.1
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.12
│ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.3.1
│ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ ├── growl@1.7.0
│ │ ├─┬ jade@0.26.3
│ │ │ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ │ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├─┬ nock@0.16.0
│ │ └── propagate@0.2.2
│ ├── node-uuid@1.2.0
│ ├── omelette@0.1.0
│ ├── should@2.0.2
│ ├─┬ sinon@1.7.3
│ │ └─┬ buster-format@0.5.6
│ │   └── buster-core@0.6.4
│ ├── streamline@0.4.5
│ ├── tunnel@0.0.2
│ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│ ├─┬ winston@0.6.2
│ │ ├── async@0.1.22
│ │ ├── colors@0.6.2
│ │ ├── cycle@1.0.3
│ │ ├── eyes@0.1.8
│ │ ├── pkginfo@0.2.3
│ │ ├── request@2.9.203
│ │ └── stack-trace@0.0.8
│ ├── winston-memory@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ xml2js@0.1.14
│ │ └── sax@0.6.0
│ └── xmlbuilder@0.4.3
├── duplexer@0.1.1
├─┬ npm@1.4.0
│ ├── abbrev@1.0.4
│ ├── ansi@0.2.1
│ ├── ansicolors@0.3.2
│ ├── ansistyles@0.1.3
│ ├── archy@0.0.2
│ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
│ ├── child-process-close@0.1.1
│ ├── chmodr@0.1.0
│ ├── chownr@0.0.1
│ ├── cmd-shim@1.1.1
│ ├── columnify@0.1.2
│ ├── editor@0.0.5
│ ├── fstream@0.1.25
│ ├─┬ fstream-npm@0.1.6
│ │ └── fstream-ignore@0.0.7
│ ├── github-url-from-git@1.1.1
│ ├── github-url-from-username-repo@0.0.2
│ ├── glob@3.2.7
│ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.1
│ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├── ini@1.1.0
│ ├─┬ init-package-json@0.0.14
│ │ └── promzard@0.2.1
│ ├── lockfile@0.4.2
│ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├── node-gyp@0.12.2
│ ├── nopt@2.1.2
│ ├── npm-install-checks@1.0.0
│ ├── npm-registry-client@0.4.0
│ ├── npm-user-validate@0.0.3
│ ├─┬ npmconf@0.1.12
│ │ └─┬ config-chain@1.1.8
│ │   └── proto-list@1.2.2
│ ├── npmlog@0.0.6
│ ├── once@1.3.0
│ ├── opener@1.3.0
│ ├── osenv@0.0.3
│ ├── path-is-inside@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ read@1.0.5
│ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4
│ ├── read-installed@0.2.5
│ ├─┬ read-package-json@1.1.7
│ │ └── normalize-package-data@0.2.9
│ ├─┬ request@2.30.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.0
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ ├── async@0.2.9
│ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.9.15
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.3
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ ├── retry@0.6.0
│ ├── rimraf@2.2.6
│ ├── semver@2.2.1
│ ├─┬ sha@1.2.3
│ │ └── readable-stream@1.0.24
│ ├── slide@1.1.5
│ ├── tar@0.1.19
│ ├── text-table@0.2.0
│ ├── uid-number@0.0.3
│ └── which@1.0.5
└── through@2.3.4
```

At last i have the exact error as writting in my azure.err as mentioned in the first block.

```
Thu Feb 13 2014 09:17:17 GMT+0100 (CET):
  2 { [Error: The provided URI "https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" is invalid.]
  3   stack: [Getter/Setter],
  4   __frame: undefined,
  5   rawStack: [Getter] }
  6 Error: The provided URI "https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" is invalid.
  7     at exports.isValidUri (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/util/validate.js:52:11)
  8     at Array.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/servicesettings.js:113:25)
  9     at Object.exports.matchedSpecification (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/servicesettings.js:226:54)
 10     at Function.StorageServiceSettings.createFromSettings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/storageservicesettings.js:254:34)
 11     at Function.StorageServiceSettings.createExplicitlyOrFromEnvironment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/storageservicesettings.js:335:55)
 12     at Function.StorageServiceClient.getStorageSettings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/storageserviceclient.js:75:53)
 13     at new BlobService (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:84:53)
 14     at Object.exports.createBlobService (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/azure.js:70:10)
 15     at Object.StorageUtil.getBlobService (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util._js:106:21)
 16     at getBlobServiceClient (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage.blob._js:217:39)
```

I hope there is someone with an idea because i can not even use the Azure service this way if i cant export a blob file to the storage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to tell because you have (obviously) changed the myaccountname part of the URI, but are you specifying the actual name in all lower case? Azure doesn't like mixed case account names.

Comment: I'm able to recreate this error if I specify an invalid account name e.g my_storage_account. Can you please check the account name?

Answer (score 0):

try another name for your account storage "mystorageaccountname" may be taken before

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Indeed i changed the name of my storage account because i'd rather dont have it public. It was all lower case without any special characters or whatsoever.

I executed the following steps

```
npm remove azure-cli -g
npm cache clear
npm install azure-cli -g
```

Now everything is working again. Even though there are still some huge issues with the CLI client because i can not use it from an Azure Micro Instance. After a while the command is killed while uploading a 200MB file.

I have people at Microsoft looking at it so maybe its good that i refer to that too:
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/issues/1063

But after reinstalling the command is running again without the error mentioned above.